# Making Prediction on logistic regression using SAS

Tags: logistic-regression, prediction, sas

```
proc logistic data= train descending;
   class Emp_status Gender Marital_status;
   model Default = Checking_amount  Term  Credit_score  Gender  Marital_status  
   Car_loan  Personal_loan  Home_loan  Education_loan  Emp_status  
   Amount  Saving_amount  Emp_duration  Age  No_of_credit_acc;
run;
```

As you can see, I already made a logistic regression on train dataset. However, how can I make the prediction on the test dataset? I checked online, but there are not many sources to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
proc surveyselect data=work.data method=srs seed=2 outall
samprate=0.7 out=work.data_subset;

data training;
set work.data_subset; *dataset in your work directory;
if selected = 1;
run;

data testing;
set work.data_subset; *dataset in your working directory;
if selected = 0;
run;

ods graphics on;
proc logistic data=work.training descending plots=roc;
class Gender /param = effect ref = first; *categorical variable;
model default = x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
/ link=logit;
score data=work.testing out=work.logisticOoutput;
run;
ods graphics off;
```

Using proc surveyselect to split the dataset 70% 30%, we can split our dataset into train and test. Then, we can run logistic regression on train data. see the performance on the test dataset.

```
score data=work.testing
```

This command is running the regression on the test set. see the result in the output.